# Timeout error while calling stored procedure from node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-modules, mssql-jdbc

When I try to call a stored procedure from node js application getting time out error

My stored procedure takes to complete their action **at least 1 hour**

I'm able to **sql running queries and my stored procedure called but terminating within 15 seconds** getting error like

**code**: 'ETIMEOUT',

**originalError**: RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms

*Please check my code*

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const sqlConfig = {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'Testdb',
  server: 'awsrdsserver',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 5000000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true, 
    trustServerCertificate: true 
  }
}

async function main () {

 try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    await pool.request().execute('test_sp');
    console.log('success')
 } catch (err) {
    console.log('error',err)
 }
}

main()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Done');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error("Database replication errored out.");
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: You tried to reach the target sql server with any other means from the problematic machine? Like with a client or something else?

Comment: [As per the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#:~:text=ms%20(default%3A%2015000).-,requestTimeout,-%2D%20Request%20timeout%20in) 15000ms is the default request timeout, but you can change this in your configuration, e.g. `requestTimeout: 3600000` will extend this to an hour

Answer (score 0):

Remove **await** **from pool.request().execute()** because u didn't need response from stored procedure or else you can also increase the request timeout, instead of that remove **await** its better option for you

Comment: after removing await still getting error RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms